# error in jenkins master and slave configuration

Tags: jenkins

I was able to login from my master to slave server through SSH, but while setting up slave node in jenkins UI. It has the following error. please give me solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr9jN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states

> No entry currently exists in the Known Hosts file for this host.
>   Connections will be denied until this new host and its associated key
>   is added to the Known Hosts file.

Check your agent configuration for "Host Key Verification Strategy", most likely you  have "Known hosts file verification strategy".